# Getting element of list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, c#-4.0, arraylist

I wrote code belown and I want to get lat and lng values but i dont know how to do it. I want to learn getting element in the list.

```
public class GeoCode
{
    public List<Results> Results { get; set; }
}
public class Results
{        
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public LL location { get; set; }
        public ViewPort viewPort { get; set; }
    }   
    public class LL
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }
    public class ViewPort
    {
        public LL northeast { get; set; }
        public LL southwest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to expand on your question. Do you want to get an element from the list by a specific property?

Comment: `Results[0]` returns first element, `foreach(var res in Results` loops through all of them, what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I want to get element "lat" and "lng" in Results list

Comment: Take a look at [C# List Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list), (`res.geometry.location.lat`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var yourList = yourGeoCode.Results
                          .Select(x=>x.geometry.location).ToList();
```

It will return a list of `LL` which has 2 properties `lat` and `lng`. If you want to get the `lat` and `lng` of the element at index 2, try this:

```
double lat = yourList[2].lat;
double lng = yourList[2].lng;
```

**NOTE:** You should name the Properties with the first letter capitalized, for example, `Lat` not `lat`.